# Grails 3.0.11 AOP annotation to preprocess commandObjects before Controller methods

Tags: spring, grails, annotations, aop

I am trying to retrieve the arguments of a grails controller method using an annotation and an Aspect that executes before the method. 
The aspect handler executes correctly but i cant access the argument(which implements `grails.validation.Validateable`) the list of arguments is empty.

*experiment.aspect.validated*

```
package experiment.aspect

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target

/**
 * Created by Vaggelis on 10/13/2016.
 */

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Validated {

}
```

*experiment.aspect.ValidatedAspect*

```
package experiment.aspect


import grails.validation.ValidationException
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before


/**
 * Created by Vaggelis on 10/13/2016.
 */
@Aspect
class ValidatedAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(experiment.aspect.Validated)")
    public void preValidate(JoinPoint point) throws ValidationException{

        println "parameters  ${point.getArgs()}"


    }
}
```

*conf.spring.resources*

```
import experiment.aspect.ValidatedAspect

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    validatedAspect(ValidatedAspect)
}
```

*controllers.experiment.TestController*

```
package experiment
import experiment.aspect.Validated
class TestController extends BaseController {
    static responseFormats = ['json']
    @Validated
    def login(LoginCommand loginCommand){
         println "Validated"
         ...
    }

}
```

*experiment.LoginCommand*

```
package experiment

/**
 * Created by Vaggelis on 9/14/2016.
 */
import grails.validation.Validateable


class LoginCommand implements Validateable {
//    String id
    String name
    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
    }
}
```

I get the following output, which means that the aspect handler method runs before the controller method but it does not get the arguments.

```
parameters []
Validated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing no args because there aren't any.

To support databinding and to keep things simpler when the servlet decides which controller and method to call, an AST transform creates a new method with the same name and no args for all action methods that have any args. The zero-arg method is the one called initially by the servlet, and it has the logic added by the transform to make the data binding calls. After that's done it then it calls your parameterized method with param strings converted to int/long/boolean/command objects/etc.

The no-arg method will also be annotated with `@grails.web.Action` and the  arg types specified in the `commandObjects` attribute. This will help find  the other method, but it's actually simple because you'll get a compiler error if you declare overloaded public methods.

Having said all that, you probably don't want to use this approach even if it did work - there's already two existing standard ways to intercept controller action calls, Grails filters (now interceptors in 3.x) and servlet filters. Grails filters and interceptors make it trivial to inspect and optionally add, modify or delete request parameters, and if you return false from a 'before' call you will stop Grails from handling the request (e.g. because you rendered it yourself, or sent a redirect, etc.)

Comment: Wouldnt that mean that both methods would be annotated? I know about interceptors, they are cool but not what i want to use for this.

Comment: No, it's used to mark the callable actions - the typed methods are effectively non-public

Comment: Great :(
But that means that if i wanted to log the duration of the action by using an Arround annotation, i would only count the time for the execution of the no-arg method.

Comment: No, you'd store the start time in the `before` part of an interceptor and subtract that from the time in the `after` part. Unless you get paid more for more complex implementations, then work as hard as you want on this solved problem :)

Comment: [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) does a good job decompiling Groovy (although something changed in the versions of Groovy used in Grails 3.x because a lot of bytecode isn't understood and is left un-decomiled) often helps shed light on the effects of ASTs. You'd see it more clearly in a 2.5 app with just a simple controller and method

Comment: Yes interceptors again :)
Your answer although not what i wanted to hear is correct it seems :)

PS: It seems i have access to the request object through the annotation target.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith filters and interceptors are of no use here. I want a command object, which can't be received in interceptors because request stream can't be read multiple times. It's pity grails doesn't honor people using AOP without suggesting an alternative.